# Reading JSON file into Pandas for analysis

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am getting myself familiar with Classes/OOP in Python and I am practicing on a basic program for tracking finances.  I have the program to the point where I add entries to a JSON file and save that file away.  Now I want to read in the JSON file into a dataframe and perform some aggregates on it.  That's where I am stuck.  The following fails with:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 7 column 2 (char 122)
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "DATE": "2019-02-01 12:57:13.140724",
    "HSA": "600",
    "401K": "90",
    "ROTH": "900",
    "SAVINGS": "1000"
}{
    "DATE": "2019-02-01 12:57:26.995724",
    "HSA": "250",
    "401K": "90",
    "ROTH": "80",
    "SAVINGS": "900"
}
```

Any ideas?

```
import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd

class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = ['HSA', '401K', 'ROTH', 'SAVINGS']
        self.records = {}
        self.now = datetime.datetime.now()



    def data_entry(self):
        for i in self.accounts:
            x = input('Enter the amount for {}:'.format(i))
            self.records['DATE'] = self.now
            self.records[i] = x


    def display(self):
        return self.records

    def savefile(self):
        with open('finance.json', 'a') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(self.records, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
            file.close()

    def analyzedata(self):
        with open('finance.json', 'r') as f:
            obj = json.load(f)
            frame = pd.DataFrame(obj, columns=['401K', 'HSA', 'ROTH', 'SAVINGS', 'DATE'])
            print(frame)





s = BankAccount()
s.data_entry()
s.savefile()
s.analyzedata()
```

BTW feel free to offer any other suggestions as to why this is a bad way to do it, i.e. using a Dictionary or whatever it may be.  Still learning.  Thanks

Comment: You have two objects in same line so try `lines=True`

Comment: No need to close a file if you're using a context manager to open it. Also you're appending a whole new json file on top of the last one every time you save this. try implementing a load method and performing this within `__init__` if there is data in the file then fill `records` with that data before you alter it. then use 'w' as your file option when you save it. This will result in a correct json file format and a sort of persistence to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data is represented as one dict, not multiple dicts in a file. This said I suggest the JSON format be basically a dict that has a key `'data'` that holds a list of `record` dicts. I also fixed a couple namimg conventions a small things I say to be easier to understand ontop of my comment.

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd

class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, filename='finance.json'):
        self.accounts = ['HSA', '401K', 'ROTH', 'SAVINGS']
        self.records = []
        self.filename = filename

        #load data upon initialization
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            #you may want to do some error checking here
            data = json.load(file)
            self.records = data.get('data', [])

    def data_entry(self):

        #make a new record with current date
        record = {'DATE': datetime.now()}
        for account_name in self.accounts:
            account_data = int(input('Enter the amount for {}:'.format(account_name)))
            record[account_name] = account_data
        self.records.append(record)

        #You made a modification to the records
        #now save it to file
        self.save_data()

    def save_data(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as file:
            #possibly some error checking here as seen fit
            file.write(json.dumps({'data': self.records}, default=str))

    def analyze_edata(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            df = pd.DataFrame(self.records, columns=self.accounts+['DATE'])
            print(df)

s = BankAccount()
s.data_entry()
s.save_data()
s.analyze_data()
```

**When Ran:** *a couple times**

```
Enter the amount for HSA:250
Enter the amount for 401K:90
Enter the amount for ROTH:80
Enter the amount for SAVINGS:900
['HSA', '401K', 'ROTH', 'SAVINGS', 'DATE']
   HSA  401K  ROTH  SAVINGS                        DATE
0  600    90   900     1000  2019-02-01 22:05:06.110471
1  360   100   250      430  2019-02-01 22:06:10.649269
2  250    90    80      900  2019-02-01 22:07:04.176700
```

**finance.json**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "401K": 90,
        "SAVINGS": 1000,
        "ROTH": 900,
        "HSA": 600,
        "DATE": "2019-02-01 22:05:06.110471"
    }, {
        "401K": 100,
        "SAVINGS": 430,
        "ROTH": 250,
        "HSA": 360,
        "DATE": "2019-02-01 22:06:10.649269"
    }, {
        "401K": 90,
        "ROTH": 80,
        "SAVINGS": 900,
        "HSA": 250,
        "DATE": "2019-02-01 22:07:04.176700"
    }]
}
```

Comment: this is great, thank you for taking the time to write this out.  Question though, when I start with an empty json file (finance.json) and I add the last 4 lines of my original code (s = BankAccount() etc....)  and run it, it errors out with json decoder error 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)  Any ideas why? Should I change how I am executing these? I dont see that part in your code so maybe I am doing it wrong.  thank you again!

Comment: Copy my .json format or just put `{}` into the .json file and start over. If you need the old data try a json verifier on google for starts

Comment: adding {} to the empty json file did the trick.  Thank you again, much appreciated!

Comment: Take note the comments I edited in that say you may want to do some error checking for valid JSON. That will allow you to handle when there is invalid JSON in there. You’d either have to parse and fix it or overwrite it with an empty dict or `{'data': []}`